# Android application starts on emulator but does not respond

Tags: android

Everything was working fine yesterday and today, my application does not respond on the emulator! It's driving me crazy as I have done nothing different or made any changes apart from updating Android Studio and I do not know if that's the cause. The app launches on the emulator but it keeps flickering on and off. Other apps work fine.

My logcat output gives me this and doesn't stop!:

```
   --------- beginning of system
08-28 14:29:16.772    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:16.772    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa370ae00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:16.890    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:17.009    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:17.009    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa28cad20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:17.233    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:17.312    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:17.312    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa29a7b60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:17.382    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:17.529    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:17.529    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa29a7b40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:17.839    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:17.883    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:17.883    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2a98dc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:17.926    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:18.097    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:18.097    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2a98da0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:18.282    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:18.339    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:18.339    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2ba3480, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:18.539    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:18.628    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:18.628    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa327f3a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:18.674    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:18.840    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:18.840    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa327f380, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:19.136    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:19.195    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:19.195    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa250aa40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:19.323    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:19.543    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:19.543    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa25843a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:19.657    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:19.840    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:19.840    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa25f0600, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:20.047    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:20.191    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:20.191    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2601260, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:20.398    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:20.461    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:20.461    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa243a740, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:20.667    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:20.771    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:20.771    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa24477e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:20.979    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
08-28 14:29:21.072    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-28 14:29:21.072    1997-2013/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2447720, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-28 14:29:21.264    1997-1997/com.example.lysandroslysandrou.myapplication I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
```

And my console is this..:

```
emulator: device fd:784
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
creating window 61 83 462 820
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not run program: Ü
draw: Could not run program: à
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: ì
draw: Could not run program: î
draw: Could not run program: î
draw: Could not run program: î
draw: Could not run program: ð
draw: Could not run program: ð
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0
draw: Could not run program: ò
```

These outputs don't stop!! Please any help will be appreciated..
If anything else is needed let me know!!

Comment: I've noticed that it may have something to do with the OpenGLRenderer as I found errors saying: GL error: out of memory and GL error: GL_INVALID_VALUE but still no solution

Comment: I have a similar problem in some applications after I replaced the graphics card of my PC. This seems to be related to my OpenGL drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references, I've solved my problem by returning to an older version of my app and starting again from there. No matter how much research I have done, I didn't find a straight forward solution. Apparently this has to do with the OpenGLRenderer but I'm not sure in which way.

Best advice I can give is to make constant copies of your app at various stages in case something like this happens. In addition, always make sure you save your files before updating Android Studio because it can mess things up and be careful at what stage of your project you update it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution to "solve" the problem, but what if you by-passed this by creating a new AVD and use it as default emulator?

Comment: I tried that already man!! I've been looking for a solution for at least 7 hours now, no jokes and nothing. I've tried new AVDs, I tried disabling GPU Host, I tried using the snapshot option and again nothing:/

Answer (score 0):

Try to create another vm.
Check gradle version.
Reinstall api packages.

Comment: Checked gradle version and reinstall APIs also, but by creating a new VM you mean another virtual device?

Comment: Yes. Try another device.

Comment: But I did, I've mentioned it above.

Answer (score -1):

I myself found emulator extremely useless. Use real android device and then you know for sure if it works or not.

Comment: I've used a real device, it crashes the thing and makes it restart. Doesn't work on it.